# Downloading Data from Google Drive Colab

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, download, google-colaboratory

I'm a beginner in TensorFlow and python in general, so any help would be much appreciated. I'm following [this tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/classification) from tensorflow, just with my own data.

So I'm trying to download my own data from a link I got from a folder that I uploaded to google drive. I will then use that data in an image classifier model. However, I start to see the images getting downloaded and it says:

```
dataset_url_training = "https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/genericid?usp=sharing" 
data_dir_training = tf.keras.utils.get_file('flower_photos', origin=dataset_url_training, untar=True)
data_dir_training = pathlib.Path(data_dir_training)
```

Downloading data from https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/genericid?usp=sharing

106496/Unknown - 2s 14us/step

And then it just stops. And when I try to use the following code:

```
print(image_count)
```

The output spits out: 0

I'm really confused and I don't know what to do. Some suggestions have been to make a zip file url, but that only applies to individual files and doesn't work for whole folders like mine. Furthermore, as far as I know, Google Drive doesn't allow you to get links for zip files, just those for sharing (they are my own files, for clarification).

Thank you.

Edit 1: Just want to be clear: I'm NOT looking for a path. I'm looking for a URL, hence the use of a directory. I've also tried using the. link of a zip file, but I got the same error message as before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you want to use a file from google drive in colab you can mount our drive to colab.

```
from google.colab import drive

drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
```

Than you can open files form google drive.
For example your file is in the directory "folder" on your main drive page:

```
path = "gdrive/My Drive/folder/flower_photos"
```

Edit/Addition:

To make it more clear, you change this part from the tutorial

```
import pathlib
dataset_url = "https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/example_images/flower_photos.tgz"
data_dir = tf.keras.utils.get_file('flower_photos', origin=dataset_url, untar=True)
data_dir = pathlib.Path(data_dir)
```

to this

```
import pathlib
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
data_dir = "gdrive/My Drive/flower_photos"
data_dir = pathlib.Path(data_dir)
```

Comment: Hi Der-Davidos, thanks for your help. However, l literally did what you said and it gives me: ValueError: unknown url type: 'gdrive/My Drive/folder/flower_photos' Edit: I also tried deleting the space, using backlashes, putting /content at the beginning, and almost any other iteration. None of them worked

Comment: I assume you still use tf.keras.utils.get_file()? Because this is for getting files from an url, as documented [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/get_file?hl=de). But you do not need to get it from the url anymore, you should be able to go on with the tutorial by using the path to your directory instead of data_dir.

Comment: Yes, I am, but the problem is how would I amend the following code if I'm not using the directory but a path instead? I would have to change all my code, so I would rather just use the URL. If you could let me know how to do that, I would really appreciate it.                                                                                                    
`ds_train = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="training",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(img_height, img_width),
  batch_size=batch_size)`

Comment: I made an addition to my answer, hopefully it is more clear now.

Comment: Thank you so much!! You legit saved my life